# Interaction of a iOS app with server

Tags: ios, json, rest, soap

I am currently working with an iOS app that needs a remote interactive server.In my app i have to request some queries as well as post some data to server.Which is the right way or appropriate way to do so. which one is better REST or JSON or SOAP to do this? Is there any tutorial or documentation site?Thanks

Comment: What server side language would you prefer?

Comment: PHP would be better for me.Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST is the most common way to do so.
Basically, REST relayes on simple HTTP requests & JSON,
both are very easy to use with iOS SDK.

If your model is simple, you can go straight forward with HTTP & JSON. 
If it's more complicated, i recommend using REST Kit, [here's a link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/)

For straight-forward solution, if you only need a simple GET call to an existing REST API,
here are a few basic lines of code (These shouldn't run on main thread)

```
// Preform this on background thread
NSError *anError;
NSData *apiCallResponseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://yourdomain.com/apicall?param=value"];
NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiCallResponseData options:kNilOptions error:&anError];
 //Lets say result is { "key" : "value" }
NSString *someFieldValue = response[@"key"];
//.. do what you need with the result values...
```

Comment: As i go through the setup of restkit to my project it seems a little bit complex.is there any suggestion or useful link that can help.Thanks@avishic

Comment: @TunvirRahmanTusher Could you describe your needs? What kind of API calls you'd like to use? Mostly update server's data / Get info from server..? How complex are the results?